# How to get sans-serif text in beamer with newtxtext?

Tags: beamer, newtx

The `beamer` package uses sans-serif fonts for text and structure. But, if the `newtxtext` package is used, all contents use serif font.

Here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: beamer with newtxtext]

As `newtxtext` is a replacement for `txfonts`, I compare with the same document but using `txfonts`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \lipsum[4]
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The `newtxtext` package defines `TeXGyre Termes` as default serif font _and_ `TeXGyreHeros` as sans-serif default font.

Comment: Would `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` be an acceptable workaround?

Comment: @samcarter Perfect! I had not noticed the line `\renewcommand*{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}` in `newtxtex.sty`! Could you turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: Done. _________

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To have the sans serif font as default, simply add `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item Item 1
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]